# How can I sideload J2ME apps on a device?

Tags: wireless-networking, mobile-phone, development, j2me

I'm starting to develop an app for Java (J2ME) phones. So far, the only way I've been able to test the app on an actual device (not emulator) is to put the jar/jad files on a web server, and download the app over a cell connection. This requires a subscription with a data plan, which I don't currently have.

I can buy a phone with a data plan, if I have to, but I'm looking for more efficient options:

1. Sideloading apps via bluetooth. It's easy to find J2ME phones with bluetooth, and copy apps from laptop or desktop to phone; but my phone won't let me install apps that have been copied. (AT&T's dev site says that such copied files are sandboxed; in order to install them, they have to be acquired OTA [over-the-air], which apparently doesn't include bluetooth.)
2. Sideloading apps via microSD card. Again it's easy to transfer the jar/jad files to a phone via microSD card, and to copy them from the card to internal memory. But I can't get a phone to install the app, probably for the same reasons as in #1. Probably there is a way, at least on some phones; how do I find it?
3. Cable connection from the computer. Similar considerations apply. I have not tried this, because I didn't find a cable that worked with a phone I have. But I could get one if I were confident that I could frequently reinstall an app on a phone from my computer by this method.
4. Have the phone access the app OTA via WiFi. That would enable me to use our home internet service via our wireless router. This seems like a dumb question, but how do I find a J2ME phone that can connect via WiFi? I have searched and come up with only chaff. Should I look for phones that support [JSR-307](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=307)?
5. OTA via a cell data subscription.

Thanks for any suggestions.
Even if it's a suggestion for a better forum to ask this question in.

If the answer involves a particular phone or service, I'm looking for something that's available in the U.S.

Comment: I came here from stackoverflow because someone on that site suggested questions like this were a better fit for SU than for SO. To those who have voted to close this q as off-topic: I can see why. But can you suggest a better place to ask? @random

Comment: You could try re-asking it at softwarerecs if the guidelines go http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: @random: softwarerecs? I'm not really asking for recommendations for software. That seems further off-topic than SU.

Comment: Nominating for reopening because 1) there doesn't seem to be any other SE site that addresses this category of questions, except possibly "Mobile Devices" which is still in proposal stage; and 2) the SU help says "cell phones or smart phones, except **insofar as they interface with your computer**" are off-topic. This question concerns the interface with the computer. Yes the Q is related to dev, which is off-topic, but non-devs also often want to know how to side-load apps.

Comment: Some J2ME phones do support running directly from the SD card without needing to copy to internal memory, and using a USB cable you can transfer files directly to the SD card on the phone. For reference my Nokia C2-01 is able to do this. It would help if you could give the model of the phone you're trying to use at the moment although given this question is almost 9 years old I assume you've moved past it.

Comment: @0x777C Thanks for your response. Yes, we've moved past this issue. I think you're saying that your Nokia C2-01 is able to sideload (install) apps that are on the SD card. That's good to know. We were looking for a general solution for J2ME phones, but now we're not targeting that platform.